# What is the simplest API to create maps like in Google Analytics?

Tags: map

I want to create maps that show the number of clicks per country, just like in Google Analytics. I've looked at Google and Bing map API. These looks way to complicate for what I want to do. Do you know of any simpler API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it looks like the tool I was looking for is not a map API, but the Google Visualization tool: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

Comment: Yes, that one is cool.  There are a couple other map-based visualization tools:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/intensitymap.html

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/map.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can't handle the Google Maps API, then I doubt you're going to be able to handle any other mapping/geo-location API. The Google Maps API is very, very easy to use and there's plenty of "wrappers" out there to make it *even easier* (such [as this one I just found on google here](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/descargar.aspx))

Comment: I've used it on another website, where I only needed to add markers. But having different colors for different countries seems to be a lot harder, I don't thinks this use case fits well with their API.